# Conditional map of Hash with join to concatenate a string

Tags: ruby

I am doing string concatenation:

```
aql_string = "FILTER user."
aql_string << conditions.map { |attr, value| "#{attr} == '#{value}'" }.join(" && user.")
```

where `conditions` may be `{ :foo => 'bar', :rating => 42 }`, in which case the result is:

```
FILTER user.foo == 'bar' && user.rating == '42'
```

Unfortunately, the Query language behind `FILTER ...` doesn't accept strings if the attribute (`user.rating` here) is assigned an `Integer`.

So I have to eliminate the single quotes around `#{value}` if `value` is an `Integer`. I tried to create a condition like `if value.class == Fixnum`. However, I don't know how to use this condition in `conditions.map` because `join` only works this way.

I tried to do something like:

```
aql_string << conditions.map do |attr, value|
  if value.class == Fixnum 
    "#{attr} == #{value}" }.join(" && user.")
  else
    "#{attr} == '#{value}'" }.join(" && user.")
end
```

but this raises an error: `` undefined method `join' for "foo == 'bar'":String ``.

Do you have an advice how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an XY-question. I think you should do it this way:

```
aql_string = "FILTER " <<
conditions.map{|k, v| "user.#{k} == #{v.inspect}"}.join(" && ")
```

This will surround strings with double quotes instead of single quotes, but I believe that is not a problem.